# Paging Library 3 Loading states not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I have an application which fetches movies from the moviedb api , i'm using paging library 3 to page the data , i have set up everything and data is showing properly , the only thing that is not working in loading states , upon reading little bit more about loading state adapter , i got to know that it only works when fetching data from db after using remote mediator , i might be wrong , someone please corrects me , i would appreciate any help ..

- Code

```
  val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager  = layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        movieAdapter = TrendingMovieAdapter(object : MovieListener{
            override fun onMovieSelected(movieId: Int) {
                Intent(this@MainActivity,DetailsActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("id",movieId)
                    startActivity(this)
                }
            }
        })
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = movieAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
            footer = LoaderAdapter(),
            header = LoaderAdapter()
        )


        lifecycleScope.launch {
            movieViewModel.getPagedTrendingMovies().collectLatest {
                movieAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
```

- LoadStatesAdapter class

```
class LoaderAdapter : LoadStateAdapter<LoaderAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(var binding : LoaderItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, loadState: LoadState): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout.loader_item,parent,false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, loadState: LoadState) {
        holder.binding.progressBar.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also config footer load state adapter same your code, there's doesn't anything to be wrong. Hmm, you can try call `executePendingBindings()` after call `holder.binding.progressBar.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading`.
This is `onBindViewHolder()` func:
`override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, loadState: LoadState) { holder.binding.progressBar.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading executePendingBindings()     }`

Comment: I basically was not binding my progressbar properly , Thank you , Do you think is it better fetch data from api , save to db and then load it using pager , or is it okey to fetch it directly , i mean which way is recommended , Thank you